# How to show timezone along with datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

In my application i have a datetime variable which i save in db after converting to UTC. I have used `DateTime.UTCNow` to convert to UTC. We get some real time information and which is in CET. Now while sending this back to the client application I would like to mention timezone also. It means for UTC Z and for CET +02:00. How can I include timezone to a datetime.
Below

```
DateTime utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;

var unspecifiedDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(utcNow, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
var tzi = TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("Europe/Brussels");

var final = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(unspecifiedDateTime, tzi);
```

But i didnt get in to the specific format i needed..i never worked on timezone and its bit complicated for me

I need something like this for UTC "2023-10-18T16:47:14.08Z" or  "2023-10-18T16:47:14.08+00:00"
and in CET 2023-10-18T16:47:14.08+02:00. this way client application can understand

Comment: You do know of [DateTimeOffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=net-7.0), right? And also, why do you need to do TimeZone consideration in the Backend? Wherever possible, it is easier done on the Client side.

Comment: I hope you also realize that `2023-10-18T16:47:14.08+00:00` and `2023-10-18T16:47:14.08+02:00` are _not_ the same instant in time?

Comment: Maybe round trip format: utcNow.ToString("o");

Answer (score 2):

For you to represent the DateTime in this format you'd like, you can just use `ToString` with a custom format string, and also some logic to get the timezone offset.

```
DateTime utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;

string utcFormat1 = utcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ"); //2023-10-18T16:47:14.08Z
string utcFormat2 = utcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz"); //2023-10-18T16:47:14.08+00:00
```

Which outputs:

```
UTC Format 1: 2023-10-19T14:10:33.430Z
UTC Format 2: 2023-10-19T14:10:33.430+00:00
```

For CET format, you convert the UTC DateTime to CET using `TimeZoneInfo`, then get CET time by using `ConvertTimeFromUtc`.

```
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time");
DateTime cetTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcNow, tzi);
```

Then you can just use `ToString` in the same way as we did before:

```
string cetFormat = cetTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz");
```

Finally giving you an output you desired:

```
CET Format: 2023-10-19T16:10:33.430+01:00
```

Learn more about what these format strings properly represent here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings